# Integration between OpenX and GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, openx

I have GWT Project and i need to add some advertisement to this project so  we decide to use OpenX as admin of creating adds to the site . so after investigation we found that the OpenX generate the code of the adds as following Example :

```
 <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
   var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'openXURL':'openXURL');
   var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
   if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
   document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
   document.write ("?what=SearchCriteria");
   document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
   if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
   document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
   document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
   if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
   if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
   if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
   document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
//]]>--></script><noscript><a href='openXURL?n=a98f1030&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='openXURL??what=SearchCriteria&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=a98f1030' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
```

So what i ask about is how can i render this javascript code in GWT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that OpenX generate the above code as ifram so i get he ifram code and add it to html panel and it works fine .